# Want to make 3D wall art how to project/bake texture from image plane to the walls of a room?

Tags: texturing, uv, image, texture-baking, distort

- I want to project a texture from plane to camera view and bake the texture to the room walls so the texture will be distorted properly for me to print.
- as people suggest to use project UV from view right now its work in 3D but texture(in image editor are still the same as we distorted UV).To be able to print fit to the wall texture need to distorted to fit rectangle plane How I would do that?

[image: Projected]

[image: Setup]

[image: CamView]

Comment: Have you tried UV unwrapping your destination wall, using the "Project From View" option?

Answer (score 4):

As Rob says, you should use the *Project From View* mode when you unwrap.

- Import your image in the the *UV Editor*. Move your camera in front of your box until you get the view you want. In *Edit* mode make sure your box is subdivided enough, otherwise the projection will bug. Press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Project From View*.

[image]

- Move or scale your UV as you want in the *UV Editor*. Create your material, load the image in the *Image Texture* node.

[image]

- If you stay in the camera view you'll see your image as it is, i.e. it will appear flat. If you move your view you'll see how the image has been projected on the surfaces.

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys this is work in 3D as we distorted UV but I need distorted texture right now the image texture is still the same and cannot be print fit to the wall I need its distorted to fit every rectangle plane how I would do that.